# Windows Kernel Development - Failed to start service: Error 1275

Tags: windows, service, kernel, driver

I have just wrote a simple kernel mode driver using Code::Blocks , and as it seems I can not successfully load it due to error 1275 which seems to be telling me that I'm trying to load a 32bit driver on a 64bit machine.

The ddk (driver development kit) seems to be a 32bit one. I couldn't find a 64bit one, therefore I have completely no idea how to recreate the driver as a 64bit driver.

*I'm using windows 8.1 64bit

This is the driver code:

```
#include "ddk/ntddk.h"

VOID __stdcall OnUnload( IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject )
{
    DbgPrint("OnUnload called\n");
}

NTSTATUS __stdcall DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT theDriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING theRegistryPath)
{
    DbgPrint("I loaded!\n");

    theDriverObject->DriverUnload  = OnUnload;

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is the load \ unload code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define false   0
#define true    1

int _util_unload_sysfile(char *driver)
{
    char string[512] = "sc delete ";
    strcat(string, driver); /* unsafe , fix later */
    system(string);
    return 1;
}

int _util_load_sysfile(char *theDriverName)
{
    char aPath[1024];
    char aCurrentDirectory[515];

    SC_HANDLE sh = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
    if(!sh)
    {
        printf("Failed in OpenSCManager");
        return false;
    }

    GetCurrentDirectory( 512, aCurrentDirectory);
    _snprintf(aPath, 1022, "%s\\%s.sys", aCurrentDirectory, theDriverName);

    printf("Loading %s\n", aPath);

    SC_HANDLE rh = CreateService(sh, theDriverName, theDriverName,  SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER,  SERVICE_DEMAND_START,   SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,   aPath,  NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL);
    if(!rh)
    {
        printf("Failed to create service: ");
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_SERVICE_EXISTS)
        {
            // service exists
            printf("Service already exists\n");
            rh = OpenService(sh, theDriverName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
            if(!rh)
            {
                CloseServiceHandle(sh);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Unknown error\n");
            CloseServiceHandle(sh);
            return false;
        }
    }

    // start the drivers
    else
    {
        printf("Starting driver\n");
        if(0 == StartService(rh, 0, NULL))
        {
            printf("Failed to start service\n");
            printf("Last error: %d\n", GetLastError());
            // if(ERROR_SERVICE_ALREADY_RUNNING == GetLastError())
            // {
                // printf("Service already running\n");
                // // no real problem
            // }
            // else
            // {
                // CloseServiceHandle(sh);
                // CloseServiceHandle(rh);
                // return false;
            // }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Service started\n");
        }
        CloseServiceHandle(sh);
        CloseServiceHandle(rh);
    }
    return true;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
C:\Users\...\Desktop>a.exe load driver
Loading C:\Users\...\Desktop\driver.sys
Starting driver
Failed to start service
Last error: 1275
```

Comment: Try to install WDK for Windows 7 and use its one of its `Build Environments` to compile the driver. There is an environment for producing 64-bit drivers. You need to create a MAKEFILE and a SOURCES file for your driver. Look into samples provided with the WDK, so you get an idea how to cope with it. Or, look into this sample (from me): https://jadro-windows.cz/download/hello.zip.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to re-create the driver you just need to download `WDK8.1` and then install with your `visual studio2013`.

After this you need to convert your project for newer WDK using `nmake2msbuild` utility [nmake2msbuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh454230%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

,then you just open your project in visual studio(.vcxproj) and set the platform as **x64**.

After that to build for `windows8.1` you have to set property **Configuration properties->Driver settings->General->Target Os Version=Windows8.1**

Now build your project and try to install the drivers. If you get any error building the project add the corresponding `SOURCES` file and `MAKEFILE` to your project and then try to build.

Comment: I am not using VS and not going to, but thanks for the answer.

Comment: May be you can use WDK also I don't remember the commands but google it you will find.